# XAML - InputBindings prevent MouseLeftButtonDown-Events being fired

Tags: c#, events, xaml

I have a class derived from ItemsControl in which I implement my own selection-algorithm which uses the MouseLeftButtonDown to change the selection.

Now I needed a specific control to handle Mouseclicks in the ViewModel, so I wrote the following:

```
<controls:DraggableItemsContainer bla="blub">
    <controls:DraggableItemsContainer.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DeselectSubGroupsCommand}" />
    </controls:DraggableItemsContainer.InputBindings>
</controls:DraggableItemsContainer>
```

What happens now is, that I don't get the MouseLeftButtonDown-event anymore - which is comprehensable because the command "e.handles" the click.

But in this case, that's not what I want. Is there a way to fire the event anyway?

PS: Yes I need to do the selection in the MouseLeftButtonDown-event and not in any Preview-event

Comment: Additional question: Do you say "what happens now is that ...." or "what now happens is that ..." ? Help me improve my english :-)

Comment: Either is fine, although "what happens now" might be a little more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- You can have your custom ItemsControl hook [`PreviewMouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) instead of [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown).
- You can continue to hook `MouseDown`, but do it by calling [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899.aspx), and pass `true` for the `handledEventsToo` parameter.

If it's important that you get notified after the `MouseBinding` has done its work, then you need to use `AddHandler`. If you're okay with getting the message first, `PreviewMouseDown` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you try to catch the same event, on the same control, using two different approaches.

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DeselectSubGroupsCommand}" />
    </Grid.InputBindings>
    <controls:DraggableItemsContainer bla="blub">
         .....
    </controls:DraggableItemsContainer>
</Grid>
```

Make sure that in your control you have `e.Handled = false`.

This should allow for your internal logic to run, and then execute the command. If you need it in the opposite order..... I don't know.